# How to change wallpaper using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, desktop-wallpaper

I need to make a batch file that changes the wallpaper to a picture that is in the same location as the bat file I currently have this code:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d c:\images\wallpaper.bmp
```

the problem with this is that it the pictures need to be in the folder c:\images\ and I need it to be in the same place as the bat file. does any one know how I could do it.

Comment: Use `%~dp0wallpaper.bmp` instead

Comment: Thanks, Post it as a answer then I can mark tick it. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `%~dp0wallpaper.bmp`

`%~dp0` returns the full path of the batch file that is being executed with a backslash at end.

You probably might want to enclose the filename in double quotes in case the batch file's directory contains spaces: `"%~dp0wallpaper.bmp"`